# Magento 2 disable Bank Transfer on website level

Tags: magento2, configuration, payment

I created two sites , website 1 and Website 2. Each website has its own store and store view.

For bank transfer, it is only available on Website A and not website B. So I clicked **STORES >>  Configuration >> Payment** Method to do the following setting:

1. Default Config:

   - Bank Transfer : Enabled
2. Website 1

   - Bank Transfer : Enabled
3. Website 2

   - Bank Transfer : Disabled

When I checkout using website 2 , I still see the bank transfer option, despite it being disabled. I even cleared the cache and why such behavior is happening and can someone please advice me? Is this a bug in Magento 2.1.3?

Answer (score 1):

For example, Websites Config looks like:

[image]

The Payment should be hidden on Website 2. We should check:

- Clear Magento Cache.
- Clear Browser Cache(can disable it for testing purpose) or try to use Incognito Browser.
- Clear Browser Local Storage.
- Check the third party extensions which relate to payment.

Comment: I tried a s per what you have suggested but it does not seem to work. I think magneto only show payment on default level for bank transfer. Even when I use the api {storecode}/bhr/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-methods. It still shows what that is enabled in default site and not in website level.

Comment: @madi See my updated answer. Your Website config should look like that.

Comment: Mine is exactly the same setup and I disabled the payment on website level. Even after disabling , I use the web interface and the api, both do not give the right list of enabled payment items. That is why I went super confused.

Answer (score 1):

Currently parameters from website configuration isn't applied to the corresponding store view due to bug. See [#7943](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7943) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 on multi store has bug and it is surprising to see that the bug was not solved by Magento 2 team. Like a version 2.1.3.1 could have been released. Nevertheless, Magento 2 team has been doing a reasonably good job but there are more rooms for improvement.

The fix to the bug is reflected here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7943

The fix is:
Go to : /app/code/Magento/Store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php and change the following code in getWebsiteConfig() method. Here is the fix:

```
private function getWebsiteConfig(array $websites, $id)
    {
        foreach ($this->scopes->get('websites') as $websiteData) {
            if ($websiteData['website_id'] == $id) {
                $code = $websiteData['code'];
                return isset($websites[$code]) ? $websites[$code] : [];
            }
        }
        return [];
    }
```

The fix is changing

> $code = $websiteData['website'] to $code = $websiteData['code']

An the multi-store setup should work. Cheers!